# Is it possible to refer @JoinColumn from one FK to the other column in another FK in JPA/hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

The questions seem confusing I guess.

**Inventory Entity**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(InventoryPK.class)
public class Inventory {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id",
                referencedColumnName = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", 
                referencedColumnName = "store_id")
    private Store store;    

    @Column()
    private int stock;

    @Column(precision = 2)
    private double price;
}
```

**Order Entity**

```
@Entity
public class SalesOrder {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", 
                referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", 
                referencedColumnName = "store_id")
    private Store store;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "order_date")
    private Date orderDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private List<OrderDetails> details;
}
```

**Order Details Entity**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(OrderDetailsPK.class)
public class OrderDetails {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", 
                referencedColumnName = "order_id")
    private SalesOrder order;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="product_id", 
                    referencedColumnName="product_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="store_id", 
                    referencedColumnName="store_id"),
    })
    private Inventory inventory;

    @Column()
    private int quantity;
}
```

Those entity will generate the following table

**Order Entity**

```
order_id  |  customer_id   |  store_id   |  order_date
======================================================
```

**Order Details Entity**

```
order_id  |  product_id   |  store_id   |  quantity
======================================================
```

Can I link the `store_id` in `OrderDetails` to the `store_id` in `SalesOrder` so I don't need to specify it in `OrderDetails`? I mean that the tables should be like the following.

**Order Entity**

```
order_id  |  customer_id   |  store_id   |  order_date
======================================================
```

**Order Details Entity**

```
order_id  |  product_id   |  quantity
=====================================
```

Why? I don't think I need to specify the `store_id` in `OrderDetails` since the information is already in the `SalesOrder`. To get the `Store`, I can do `OrderDetails#Order#Store`. But, currently I need to specify the `store_id`, because it's the PK in `Inventory`. Can I link the `store_id` for `Inventory` to the one from `Order`?

Comment: Inventry has store_id, and OrderEntity has store_id. Why do u keep track of Inventry in OrderDetails Entity?

Comment: because the `OrderDetails` is a list of products which costumer buy in a store, and list of products is different in each store. I put the list of `Product` available in a store in `Inventory`.

Comment: So, let the inventry contain a list of products and keep the id of the inventory(inventry Id) in OrderDetails. 
Would it work for you? I think this is a issue with your design.

Comment: so, you mean that I need to add a dedicated PK for `Inventory`? Currently I use `product_id` and `store_id` as PK for `Inventory` since those two columns are unique for every records.

Comment: What is there's an order for a different customer and he/she bought the same product_id from the same store_id ? Won't there be a conflict?

Comment: one customer can order many products in one store, but they can order in another store too. many customers can buy the same product in one store. so, different customers can buy the same product in the same store. They will have different `order_id` though. But, one customer can have many orders in one store, but different date. Even, they can buy the same product in a store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...thats what we call ManyToMany relation.
Use @ManyToMany annotation to achieve this ...
Example :-http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/ManyToManyJoinTableJoinInverseJoinColumn.htm

Comment: why should I have `@ManyToMany` on `SalesOrder`-`OrderDetails` relationship when one `SalesOrder` can have many `OrderDetails`, and one `OrderDetails` cannot be on many `SalesOrder`?